# Find neighbors delimitations with google maps or google api

Tags: google-maps, geolocation

I need to find points that define delimitations of neighbors from Chicago. 
My question is: How can I find a list with latitudes/longitudes of all the points that delimit neighbors. For example:
 Gold Coast from Chicago is a polygon with 6 points as seen on google map: http://maps.google.com/maps/ms?ie=UTF8&t=m&vpsrc=6&source=embed&oe=UTF8&msa=0&msid=206241844247425110008.0004b43f0262868b8037f

What is the best way to extract this points so I can draw poly-lines over google map with google API for specific neighbors?

Comment: Are you looking for neighborhoods?

Comment: I have the list with neighbors. I need the gps coordinates to draw each neighbor on google map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edited:
So with addresses, which you already have, you can create a Maps API site:
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/

and use the [Geocoding API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding.html) to get the latitude and longitude of each of the addresses.

Added: Seems based on your comment that you're looking for neighborhood boundary data. Google Maps doesn't provide that data. There are different venders that do, one I have heard of is the [Zillow Neighborhood API](http://www.zillow.com/howto/api/neighborhood-boundaries.htm). I have never used it so I don't know much about it.

Comment: So I see that my question was not understood. I will try to explain it in more details. I do not need to geocode and address and display it on the map. This I already done. I need to draw poly-lines on the map with neighbors. For example I want to highlight this neighborhoods from Chicago with polygons: Gold Coast, Chinatown, Hyde Park, Lakeview, Lincoln Park. To do this I need to know the polyline points to draw it on the map with google api.

Comment: Based on your answer I searched about Chicago neighborhood boundary data and found this link from Chicago mayor office: http://data.cityofchicago.org/Facilities-Geographic-Boundaries/Boundaries-Neighborhoods-KML/buma-fjbv
This helped me to extract the boundaries as I wanted. Strange that google does not offer this service.

Comment: Neighborhoods have fluid boundaries, they are generally not officially recognized. Some larger cities do publish that data, but that doesn't always correspond to what people use. And they change a lot over time.